# How can I recreate the slider of testimonials section of the following link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I would like to recreate the testimonials section of [Kanbanize](https://kanbanize.com/) with the vertical and horizontal sliders. I'm not sure how to recreate the functionality where both sliders are connected to each other so when one moves the other does too. I normally use Swiper for carousels/sliders and I think Kanbanize uses Swiper too. Can somebody recreate it and show me or at least explain how to it? Very much appreciatted

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a click event to the slider on the left to trigger a change in slide of the other (the one on the right).

`swiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)`

Check the [Swiper API documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)